# Can we run an induction motor by sequentially applying DC voltage to the windings of stator?

Tags: dc-motor, electromagnetism, brushless-dc-motor, induction-motor, ac-motor

We know that in induction motors, 3-phase AC input is applied to 3 windings of stator in order to generate changing magnetic flux in the rotor.  What would happen if we apply 3 DC voltages sequentially to the windings of stators instead? (on, off, off / off, on, off / off, off, on)
In such a case we still have a rotating magnetic field which leads to the change of flux in the rotor. Can such an input run the induction motors?

Comment: thats similar to how a brushless DC motor works (BLDC).

Comment: As Neil wrote below, it would saturate after one or two cycles. If you can supply negative voltages as well (both +on and -on), you have built yourself a basic three-level inverter. If power is low enough, I suppose you can use DC blocking capacitors and somehow make it work anyway, but transistors are cheaper than capacitors.

Comment: If it's going on and off, it isn't DC!

Answer (score 3):

An on/off sequence of a DC supply would rapidly saturate the stator, and as a result, the changing component of the magnetic field would plummet. While you would actually have a little bit of torque produced, it would probably be so low as to fail to overcome friction of the unloaded motor. It would certainly be inadequate to use as a motor to drive any sort of load.

You would need to sequence the drive as +ve/off/-ve/off, to yield zero DC on the windings. This is exactly what a VFD, aka Variable Frequency Drive, does, or in fact any brushless motor ESC.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how the simplest DC brushless motors and stepper motors work.

The magnetic saturation is solved either by a flyback circuit, an additional windings wound backwards or a bipolar drive for each of the windings.

In the simplest case the motor is not 3- but 2-phase.